# Delete from multiple Mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I am trying to delete from two mysql tables using `JOIN`.

This is how I tried it. But it doesn't work for me.

```
DELETE FROM services, images
LEFT JOIN images ON images.service_id = services.id 
WHERE services.id = 3;
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use explicit Join syntax

```
delete s,i from services s
left join images i on i.service_id = s.id 
where s.id = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete from one table but based on join then use below-

```
DELETE s FROM services s
JOIN images m ON m.service_id = s.id 
WHERE s.id = 3;
```

If you want to delete from 2 tables-

```
DELETE s, m FROM services s
LEFT JOIN images m ON m.service_id = s.id 
WHERE s.id = 3;
```